# How can I extract only the integer from a String JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a string that looks like:

```
var a = "value is 10 ";
```

How would I extract just the integer 10 and put it in another variable?

Comment: Is always the value equals 10? or it maybe be another?

Comment: Always the same format?  "value is x"?

Comment: no the value will not always be 10

Comment: Please use the search.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a regex:

```
var val = +("value is 10".replace(/\D/g, ""));
```

`\D` matches everything that's **not** a digit.

Answer (score 1):

you can use regexp

```
var a = "value is 10 ";
var  num = a.match(/\d+/)[0] // "10"
console.log ( num ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use some string matching to get an array of all found digits, then join them together to make the number as a string and just parse that string.

```
parseInt(a.match(/\d/g).join(''))
```

However, if you have a string like 'Your 2 value is 10' it will return 210.

Answer (score 0):

You do it using regex like that

```
const  pattern = /\d+/g;

const result = yourString.match(pattern);
```

Comment: `const` is JS version specific not supported by all browsers